# Kendo Grid -- custom command doesn't fire after popup edit close

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've noticed that my custom Grid command is not working after a popup edit dialog is opened and closed (cancelled).

The command `delrow` is used to display a custom delete confirmation (I've simplified it in the fiddle to just use a standard JS confirmation).

I've setup a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XNcmt/55/) that demonstrates the problem.

It works when the grid is initially loaded, but not after a cancelled edit. Not sure if this is a bug or something I'm doing wrong.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the way you do it. You are binding the click event in the `dataBound` but when you cancel the edition the row is refreshed and you loose the bind.

You should define the action using `click` property as:

```
columns   : [
    {
        command: [
            {name: 'edit'},
            {name:'delrow', click: delRow}], 
            title: '&nbsp;',
            width: 100 
        },
        { field: "FirstName", width: 90, title: "First Name" },
        ...
```

Where `delRow` is the same code that you have as click event handler:

```
function delRow(e) {
    var row = $(this).parents('tr:first');
    var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row!");
    if (r==true)
    {
        var g = grid.data('kendoGrid');
        g.removeRow(row[0]);
    }
}
```

See it in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/XNcmt/56/

Comment: Thanks OnaBai. That makes sense. Can you think of a way of getting a reference to the grid in which the `delRow` button was clicked. This will allow me to share the `delRow` function on pages that have multiple grids. Thanks again.

Comment: You can get the reference to the grid doing `$(e.delegateTarget).data("kendoGrid");`

Comment: BTW: If what you need is a simple confirmation message, why do not set in `editable` the property `confirmation` to `true`?

Comment: Hi OnaBai. That's brilliant thanks. As for the confirmation message... I'm actually showing a Bootstrap modal dialog (or something very similar). I just removed it for simplicity in the Fiddle. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you check the new notifications in the last release of Kendo UI... they are cool!

Comment: I must admit -- I haven't seen them. I'll take a look, because as soon as I add `$(e.delegateTarget).data("kendoGrid");` into the `delRow` function, it stops working.

Comment: Okay. Sorted it. For some reason, if I use `$(e.delegateTarget).data("kendoGrid")` to refer to the grid, I can no longer use `$(this).parents('tr:first')` to refer to the row - I have to use `$(e.currentTarget).parents('tr:first')` which works fine. Just had a quick look at the notifications... very cool!